# How to delete all data of previous Flask session?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I delete all the data stored in a SQLAlchemy database for a Flask app after a set amount of time (e.g. 3 minutes)? I have multiple tables with many rows that are filled by different functions, so I am looking for a way to delete the entire database without having to use a query for each table.

Here is an example of how I get the data I want to delete:

'''

```
 @bp.route('/result/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def result():
    task_name = session['task_name']
    series_id = session['series_id']

@bp.route('/reports/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def reports(series_id=None):
    series_dict = {}

    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'series_id' in request.args.keys():
            series_id = request.args['series_id']
            reports = db.session.query(Report).filter_by(series_id=series_id).order_by(Report.created_at.desc())
```

'''

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all the tables and delete the content, the following example should fulfill your needs.

```py
def clear_data():
    meta = db.metadata
    for table in reversed(meta.sorted_tables):
        db.session.execute(table.delete())
    db.session.commit()
```

You can place the code anywhere in your application that the scope allows. So you can call up the code wherever you want. One possibility would be to place the code parallel to your routes.  Where you want to delete the data, you call the function using `clear_data()`.
Here is an example of emptying all tables within an endpoint.

```
@app.route('/clear')
def clear():
    clear_data()
    return redirect('/')
```

Please note that deleting all data in the database will also delete all your users and consider whether **"deleting all data from the database"** is really what you want.

Comment: where should this piece of code go? I have pasted it in the same script where I have added the functions (added in the edit of this question) but it doesn't work

Comment: I added further explanations to my answer. From the snippets of your code I can not see what you really want to achieve.